# How to directly call the laravel sanitize function?

Tags: laravel

In a blade file one can do this:

```
{{ $someVariable }}
```

This sanitizes $someVariable as opposed to calling it like this:

```
{!! $someVariable  !!}
```

What PHP function is called for the first case? Is there a way to do this outside of a blade file?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data "Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that ends up being called is `e`, for 'escape'.

> "Encode HTML special characters in a string."

`{{ ... }}` is replaced with `<?php echo e(...); ?>`.

It is defined in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php`. It calls `htmlspecialchars` but also handles special objects that are `Htmlable` or `DeferringDisplayableValue`.

> "The `e` function runs PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function with the `double_encode` option set to `true` by default" - [Laravel 9.x Docs - Helpers - String Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-e) - `e`

On a side note, this is not sanitizing, it is just escaping.

Comment: What would you rate is the difference between sanitizing and escaping? I just want it to avoid posting malicious code?

Comment: @coderama sanitizing is removing data, like the html tags or javascript from what you have and saving it with that removed ... escaping is just encoding it so the browser doesn't see it as markup

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data) you can do it with `htmlspecialchars()`

Example:

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php